# Is it bad convention to assign the value of a constant to a temporary variable?

Tags: php, conventions

Is there anything wrong with assigning the value of a constant to a temporary variable before using it? I think it improves readability.

For instance, does anything seem wrong with this?

```
class MyClass {
  const MY_CONSTANT
  function myFunction(){
    $my_constant = self::MY_CONSTANT;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $my_constant";
    ...
    $sql = "INSERT ... INTO $my_constant";
    ...
  }
```

Or in another case:

```
$join = "LEFT JOIN $products_table ON $reports_table.$hash = $products_table.$hash";
```

vs

```
$join = "LEFT JOIN ".Products::TABLE_PRODUCT." ON ".self::TABLE_REPORTS.".".self::FIELD_PRODUCT_HASH." = ".Products::TABLE_PRODUCT.".".self::FIELD_HASH;
```

Comment: No, it is not..

Comment: In my eyes this confuses more that it enhances readability, since you have to trace where that variable comes from. If using the constant directly instead one knows immediately: that is a class constant value.

Comment: I personally would not do this.  Kind of like `$name = $array['name'];`

Comment: On the contrary. This does indeed improve readability over the string concatenation example. If it requires dozens of temporary variables, less so. It might be better to solve the configurability option at the database API layer.

Comment: You have to trace back any variable. Frankly it makes very little difference.